# I2C communication on Raspberry Pi 3B using smbus2

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, i2c, python-3

I'm trying to connect my energy measurement IC with Raspberry Pi 3B using the I2C protocol. I'm using `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` to detect the connected devices and it is correctly showing the address(7-bits) of the connected IC.
The IC contains a various registers of 8,16,24 and 32-bits. The register addresses are 16-bits long and I'm using the following code to access a register `0x021C(24-bits)` and write registers `0xFE(8-bit) and 0x0120(16-bit)`

**Python Code**

```
from smbus2 import SMBus

bus = SMBus(1)

address = 0x38

bus.write_byte_data(address,0xFE,0xAD)  #Writing single byte of data
bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0x120,[0x00,0x30])  #Writing multiple bytes of data to the register
block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0x21C,3)  #Reading multiple bytes of data from the register
print(block)

bus.close()
```

The output should be `[0x8D,0xXX,0xXX]` but the code is producing output as `[0,0,0]`

- **Question-1**: Is giving 16-bit address allowed in this Library or not?
- **Question-2**: If allowed then why the code is not working?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You seem to be using "read block".  I vaguely remember that requires "bus stretching".

Answer (score 0):

All I2C parameters are 8-bit.

To send a 16-bit value you must send two  8-bit values.

To send a 24-bit value you must send three 8-bit values.

You must also send the values in the order expected by the device.  This may be least significant value first or most significant value first.

Comment: I've tried what you are mentioning but the functions only accept only integer values for the register address.
```read_block_data(i2c_addr, register, force=None)

Read a block of up to 32-bytes from a given register.

Parameters: 

i2c_addr (int) – i2c address

register (int) – Start register

force (Boolean) –

Returns:
 
List of bytes

Return type: 
list```

Comment: I suggest you experiment with [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html).  Only use i2co, i2crd, and i2cwd.

Comment: Take a look at adafruit blink library, similar to smbus but less protocol specific:  in particular look at something like writeto_then_readfrom(address, buffer_out, buffer_in, *, out_start=0, out_end=None, in_start=0, in_end=None, stop=False), it might enable you to do what you are attempting